# Have I actually found a real bug in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE dblog_query_strings
(
    id          bigserial,
    query_string        text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    UNIQUE          (query_string)
)

CREATE TABLE dblog_file_paths
(
    id          bigserial,
    file_path       text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    UNIQUE          (file_path)
)

CREATE TABLE db_log
(
    id          bigserial,
    logged_at       timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    query_string_id     bigint NOT NULL,
    file_path_id        bigint NOT NULL,
    seconds         numeric,
    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    FOREIGN KEY     (query_string_id) REFERENCES dblog_query_strings (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY     (file_path_id) REFERENCES dblog_file_paths (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

**The application code, which is indeed run at the same time by many different scripts:**

```
$query_string = 'test query string';
$file_path = 'test path';
$seconds = 0.00065708160400391;
dbcall('INSERT INTO dblog_query_strings (query_string) VALUES ($1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING', $query_string);
dbcall('INSERT INTO dblog_file_paths (file_path) VALUES ($1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING', $file_path);
dbcall('INSERT INTO db_log (query_string_id, file_path_id, seconds) VALUES
(
    (SELECT id FROM dblog_query_strings WHERE query_string = $1),
    (SELECT id FROM dblog_file_paths WHERE file_path = $2),
$3)', [ $query_string, $file_path, $seconds ]);
```

**The SOMETIMES logged error, for example right when I clear the database log:**

```
pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  null value in column "query_string_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 2020-08-27 00:37:32.419107+02, null, null, 0.00065708160400391).
```

**Analysis:**

The third INSERT sometimes gets `null`s for its `SELECT`s, instead of the expected strings. **This should be logically impossible, regardless of whether I run one script or 10,000 scripts in parallel**, because even if the other scripts `INSERT` at the same time, and all but the first one fail, this is built into my mechanism, as you can see.

The first two queries simply INSERT values if they don't exist. It thus doesn't matter how many concurrent scripts are being run. By the time the third and final INSERT is executed, the table is guaranteed to have those values in it. Yet this is clearly not always the case! But I don't see how that is possible.

At this point, I'm 99% convinced that I've somehow hit a bug in PostgreSQL, but I'd much rather have this be a mistake/confusion by me.

I don't see any way which in which the third INSERT can possibly ever get null values from those SELECTs, given that the queries *before* make sure that the values exist, prior to it being executed. They are not "asynchronous" but executed sequentially, one by one. I've tried it like this and as a single transaction. Nothing helps from the dreaded "magical" race conditions or whatever is really happening here.

**This is how I "clear the log":**

```
dbcall('BEGIN');
dbcall('TRUNCATE TABLE db_log RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE');
dbcall('TRUNCATE TABLE dblog_query_strings RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE');
dbcall('TRUNCATE TABLE dblog_file_paths RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE');
dbcall('COMMIT');
```

While that transaction is being executed, tons of scripts are doing the INSERTs, but this doesn't matter since they will either see the old tables or completely empty ones... right? So how can I get errors still?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112338/discussion-on-question-by-markevion-have-i-actually-found-a-real-bug-in-postgres).

Answer (score 2):

Single query pattern:

```sql
WITH
insert_into_dblog_query_strings AS (
INSERT INTO dblog_query_strings (query_string) 
    VALUES ( $1 ) 
    ON CONFLICT (query_string) DO UPDATE SET id = dblog_query_strings.id
    RETURNING id
),
insert_into_dblog_file_paths AS (
INSERT INTO dblog_file_paths (file_path) 
    VALUES ( $2 ) 
    ON CONFLICT (file_path) DO UPDATE SET id = dblog_file_paths.id
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO db_log (query_string_id, file_path_id, seconds)
SELECT insert_into_dblog_query_strings.id, insert_into_dblog_file_paths.id, $3
FROM insert_into_dblog_query_strings
CROSS JOIN insert_into_dblog_file_paths;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3a02515d8a2435997f409b2f0bbecec4)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a simple race condition.

Nothing keeps a concurrent session from deleting a row created by the first two inserts before the third one starts.

The solution would be pessimistic locking to prevent that.

You can use logic like this:

```
LOOP
    var1 := NULL;

    SELECT id INTO var1
    FROM dblog_query_strings
    WHERE query_string = $1
    FOR UPDATE;

    IF var1 IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO dblog_query_strings (query_string)
        VALUES ($1)
        RETURNING id INTO var1;
    END IF;

    EXIT WHEN var1 IS NOT NULL;
END LOOP;

LOOP
    var2 := NULL;

    SELECT id INTO var2
    FROM dblog_file_paths
    WHERE file_path = $1
    FOR UPDATE;

    IF var2 IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO dblog_file_paths (file_path)
        VALUES ($1)
        RETURNING id INTO var2;
    END IF;

    EXIT WHEN var2 IS NOT NULL;
END LOOP;

INSERT INTO db_log (query_string_id, file_path_id, seconds)
VALUES (var1, var2, $3);
```

That whole code will have to run in a single transaction. If you encounter a deadlock, you have to repeat the transaction.